# Java multithread for chunk job

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I have requirement where I need to make a http call . I need to send about 5k http requests, I am thinking to use the java ExecuterService and also need to capture the Time took each thread to complete the request. Where I can publish the report for each request.

Is there any way I can capture time took by each thread to complete the transaction?

Answer (score -1):

No. You have to code to calculate difference between start and transaction end time.

```
public void method() {
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  // transaction here
  System.out.println("Total time taken " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}
```

Comment: In other words 'yes'.